# installing octave on OS X - get error and not sure how to fix

Tags: macos, homebrew, octave

I have done a `brew update && brew upgrade` and

```
brew install octave --without-docs
```

afte a while I get:

```
patching file libgui/qterminal/libqterminal/unix/ExtendedDefaultTranslator_mac.h
patching file libgui/qterminal/libqterminal/unix/KeyboardTranslator.cpp
patching file src/mkoctfile.in.cc
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.1 --disable-docs --without-opengl --with-x=no
==> make all
make[4]: *** [array/array_libarray_la-int8NDArray.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
  https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science/issues

Mon Sep 29$ cd ~/Applications/
```

I have googled and nothing seems to be coming up. Any ideas on how to fix this or what is going on?

thx

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/1193

Comment: thx - I have tried a bunch of the different scenarios but other errors pop up. I was able to download the package and then just removed the GUI version. the brew version isn't up to reasonable standards